# How to determine if function doesn't return anything?

Tags: php, function, return

Is there a way to do this in PHP, using Reflection or something?

```
function a{
  return null;
}

function b{

}


$a = a(); // null
$b = b(); // null :(
```

Comment: Functions return `null` by default, so no, not really.

Comment: Out of interest when would you need this?

Comment: A plugin system. I want to find out if the hooks represent filters or events (events should not return anything). I don't want to create separate functions for them :P

Comment: I would be more explicit in the registration of such functions, i.e. `addEventHook()` or `addFilter()`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I don't like lol

Comment: Well, that's your prerogative; it would avoid the "shooting oneself in the foot" problem though; what if a function wants to be both? :)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not explicitly return something then functions will return `null` by default. That is just how functions work in PHP, and there is no way of finding out if the function has a return value.

This should not be a problem, though. If a function returns null it usually means that nothing was done, or that nothing was found, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As you are defining your own functions, you should know yourself if they are returning anything or not.

By in any case. A function returns null by default unless you have overridden the return

```
function A (){   
}

function B(){
 return 'Test';
}

function C(){
return;
}

function CheckValidation ($Var){
    if (is_null($Var)){
        return 'Sample Is Null';
    }else{
        return 'Sample Is Not Null and returned a value!';
    }
}

echo CheckValidation(A()); // Will output: 'Sample Is Null'
echo CheckValidation(B()); // Will output: 'Sample Is Not Null and has returned a value!
echo CheckValidation(C()); // Will output: 'Sample Is Null'
```

The function I have provided is the best you are going to get, due to the fact a function returns null by default if there is no return that is..

Answer (score 0):

*mind not to return it `null` because it will definitely display no results.*

instead try to add an `echo` statement inside for checking or `return` it with a value but still in either case you still have to use `echo` to output results.....

Also refer to **PHP.NET** on proper way how to create a [USER DEFINE FUNCTION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: is there a justification for voting down?

Comment: I do not see a reason for a downvote for this answer.. It's logical, the only reason I guess is because you have included an `echo` which does not return nothing, just gives output; so the function will be returning a null even know output is given