# Undefined variable: bg footer.php file - Realtor wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php question. Something I have not run into much with wordpress. Trying to add a bit of code to one of my websites and am getting an error. It is a google map api:

`<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSy**********************-8D********&callback=initMap"type="text/javascript"></script>`

I normally add it just before the last closing tag on footer.php file. Strange thing this time I get Notice:

Undefined variable: bg in `/home2/drlf27jh/public_html/wp-content/themes/realtor-child/footer.php on line 1>`.

I have checked and Google API's is recognizing the code and passes test. The weird thing, if I delete the line for the API I added to get rid of error, the error now still remains. The only way I can get rid of the error is ftp a new footer.php file with exact same code but untouched by me adding anything additional.

Below is complete footer.php file with code I added.

```
    <?php $options = _WSH()->option();
    //printr($options);
    $bg = sh_set( $options, 'footer_bg' );
    ?>
    <!--======= FOOTER =========-->

    <footer <?php if($bg):?>style="background-image: url('<?php echo 
    esc_url($bg); ?>');"<?php endif;?>>  

    <div class="container"> 
    <!--======= NEWSLETTER =========-->
    <?php if(sh_set($options, 'footer_top')):?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-top-sidebar'); ?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if(sh_set($options, 'footer_middle')):?>
    <ul class="row">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar'); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    </footer>
    <!--======= RIGHTS =========-->
    <?php if(sh_set($options, 'footer_bottom')):?>

    <div class="rights">
    <div class="container">

    <p class="font-montserrat"><?php echo balanceTags(sh_set($options, 
    'copy_right'));?></p>
    </div>
    </div>
      <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSy**********************-8D********&callback=initMap"type="text/javascript"></script>

    </html>
```

Comment: The error message you've included here indicates that the error is on "line 1>". What's the ">" really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry community figured this one out on my own. It was not bad code above but new computer. Installed Filezilla on new computer and forgot to change transfer settings from auto to binary. Ran into this before but forgot about it. Filezilla set to Auto for file transfer occasionally will change your code when uploading and was to this file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like function sh_set is not returning anything, so $bg is null.  See [How to determine if function doesn't return anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027445/how-to-determine-if-function-doesnt-return-anything)

Comment: No, if `$bg` is null, it's still defined. The error indicates that it's not even defined.